# Alphabetical file numbering system

Tags: sequence, filenames, alphabetical

Frequently I wish to output a number of files with names like `file-1`, `file-2`, and so on.  However, if there are 10 or more files, the alphabetical ordering of the files will not be the same as the numerical ordering, since `file-10` falls between `file-1` and `file-2`.

If I know in advance how many files there will be, I can pad the lower numbers with 0s.  But I would like to do this in a "streaming" fashion, without knowing in advance how many files there will be.

That is, I want an infinite sequence of strings S(n) such that:

1. S(i) lexicographically precedes S(i+1) for any i
2. S(i+1) can be computed in O(log(i)) time, given S(i)
3. The maximum length of strings S(i) for i<=n is in O(log(n))

Is there any sequence that satisfies these conditions?

Comment: I don't understand why this was downvoted.  Is something unclear about the question?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a partial solution.  For simplicity, this only uses the symbols `0` and `1`.

S(1) is the string `1`.  To generate S(i+1) from S(i):

- If S(i) consists of all `1`s, then i+1 is a power of 2.  Append log2(i+1) `0`s to S(i).
- Otherwise, increment the binary number represented by S(i).

The sequence begins:

`1`, `10`, `11`, `1100`, `1101`, `1110`, `1111`, `1111000`, `1111001`, ...

This produces a sequence of strings whose lengths grow as O((log(i))^2), which is not quite what I would like.  Also the resulting strings are not very human-readable.